# What does the three black card icon represent?

Tags: card-of-darkness

Might have missed it in the tutorial but what does this three black card icon represent? When I use those cards, nothing in particular happens. Does it trigger whether I receive a card upon completing the level? (If so, the rewards do not appear to stack.)

[image: three black card]

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I think it means that the card has been affected by one of the Cards of Darkness equipped prior to the level start.

For example, here’s a shot after equipping the card that turns all gold to “1”:

[image: gold]